# Select vertex if vertex color is dark

Tags: python, scripting

I've baked AO to vertex colors and would like to use the smooth modifier only on vertices that have a vertex color darker than 0.1 (for example).

How can I select vertices whose colors are below that threshold? I'd then create a vertex group from that and use it in the modifier.

I know you can access the vertex colors with `bpy.context.object.data.vertex_colors.active.data[0].color`.

Comment: It's possible that 1 vertex has at 2 or more (4..5..6) different colors associated with it (for each of the corners of the surrounding faces).

Comment: If your script is only going to check greyscale, you can just check the value of the red: `if bpy.context.object.data.vertex_colors.active.data[0].color[1] < .1:`

Comment: There are currently two questions here, "how to convert Vertex Colors to Groups" and "how to subtract values below a value from a Vertex Group". While they can be done in one step in a script, I think they should still be asked separately.

Comment: I think it's still valid as a single question: how to parametrically assign a vertex to a vertex group, in this case the parameter is the vertex's own color.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Aldrik, that perhaps unbeknownst to GregZaal this question requires somewhat elaborate answers. 1) getting the colors attached to a vertex (do you select weighted average or mean?) then 2) selecting verts based on some critera (trivial) 3) the smooth modifier portion / vertex group portion. Essentially making a complete answer very long. Rather split your questions into atomic/modular parts, so that others may benefit from the individual sections of these answers.

Comment: I would agree with this. I would be interested in contributing to some solutions to combining the per-face vertex colors into a per vertex, vertex color; a constraint I for an export format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you a dictionary of colors attached to each vertex:

in the form `{vertex_index :  [ color(s) ] ,... }` .

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors['Col']

tk = {}
i = 0
for poly in mesh.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        loop = mesh.loops[idx]
        v = loop.vertex_index
        linked = tk.get(v, [])
        linked.append(color_layer.data[i].color)
        tk[v] = linked
        i += 1

print(tk)
```

There are nicer ways to write this, using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). In this example I also import [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#pprint) to nicely display the vertex<-->colors dict (`tk`).

```
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict

tk = defaultdict(list)

mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors['Col']

i = 0
for poly in mesh.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        loop = mesh.loops[idx]
        color = color_layer.data[i].color
        tk[loop.vertex_index].append(color)
        i += 1

# you must cast this as a dict manually like  tk = dict(tk) , 
# if you need it as a dict, but defaultdict will behave mostly the same
import pprint
pprint.pprint(tk)
```

This will get you as far as being able to average the colors. The output for this `Col` (for sake of simplicity i use a 9 vertex planar surface)

[image]

is

```
{0: [Color((0.800000011920929, 0.4313725531101227, 0.04313725605607033))],
 1: [Color((0.11372549086809158, 0.800000011920929, 0.0))],
 2: [Color((0.27450981736183167, 0.27843138575553894, 0.27843138575553894))],
 3: [Color((0.7882353067398071, 0.7921568751335144, 0.800000011920929))],
 4: [Color((0.800000011920929, 0.4313725531101227, 0.04313725605607033)),
     Color((0.27450981736183167, 0.27843138575553894, 0.27843138575553894))],
 5: [Color((0.11372549086809158, 0.800000011920929, 0.0)),
     Color((0.7882353067398071, 0.7921568751335144, 0.800000011920929))],
 6: [Color((0.7882353067398071, 0.7921568751335144, 0.800000011920929)),
     Color((0.27450981736183167, 0.27843138575553894, 0.27843138575553894))],
 7: [Color((0.800000011920929, 0.4313725531101227, 0.04313725605607033)),
     Color((0.11372549086809158, 0.800000011920929, 0.0))],
 8: [Color((0.800000011920929, 0.4313725531101227, 0.04313725605607033)),
     Color((0.11372549086809158, 0.800000011920929, 0.0)),
     Color((0.7882353067398071, 0.7921568751335144, 0.800000011920929)),
     Color((0.27450981736183167, 0.27843138575553894, 0.27843138575553894))]}
```

To complete this, here's an example of how to average a list of colors (naturally, for greyscale colors you only have to concentrate on 1 component as R,G and B should all be the same.

```
import pprint
from mathutils import Color

cols = tk[8]   # unadulterated color list for that vertex
pprint.pprint(cols)

def avg_col(cols):
    avg_col = Color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    for col in cols:
        avg_col += col/len(cols)
    return avg_col

print('average')
col = avg_col(cols)
print(col)
```

Now using the `defaultdict` that represents the vertices and their occurrence in `vertex_colors` you can average them, or do whatever calculations and create a new dict with a dict comprehension.

```
import pprint
import bpy

vcol_averages = {k: avg_col(v) for k, v in tk.items()}
pprint.pprint(vcol_averages)

''' outputs, nicely the averages.
{0: Color((0.800000011920929, 0.4313725531101227, 0.04313725605607033)),
 1: Color((0.11372549086809158, 0.800000011920929, 0.0)),
 2: Color((0.27450981736183167, 0.27843138575553894, 0.27843138575553894)),
 3: Color((0.7882353067398071, 0.7921568751335144, 0.800000011920929)),
 4: Color((0.5372549295425415, 0.3549019694328308, 0.16078431904315948)),
 5: Color((0.45098039507865906, 0.7960784435272217, 0.4000000059604645)),
 6: Color((0.5313725471496582, 0.5352941155433655, 0.5392156839370728)),
 7: Color((0.45686274766921997, 0.615686297416687, 0.021568628028035164)),
 8: Color((0.4941176474094391, 0.5754902362823486, 0.2803921699523926))}
'''
```

From this you might create a list of vertex indices following a threshold test.

```
vertices_of_interest = [k for k, v in vcol_averages.items() if v.r < 0.5]

pprint.pprint(vertices_of_interest)
# [1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
```

Selecting vertices, is easy once you get to this point.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your weight group there are a couple of ways to modify it:

1. You can use the *group remove* setting of the [Vertex Weight Edit Modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Modify/Vertex_Weight#Vertex_Weight_Edit_Modifier).

   > *Group Remove*
   >
   > Removes vertices with a final weight below Rem Threshold from the vertex group.
2. Alternatively you could use the <kbd>Weights | Clean</kbd> operator: [bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_clean](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_clean).